# Referencing Helm Redis master from another pod within Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

I am running Redis via Helm on Kubernetes and wondering how I reference the master pod from my application which is also running inside of Kubernetes as a pod. Helm is nice enough to create `ClusterIP` services, but I am still unclear in my application what I put to always reference the master:

```
MacBook-Pro ➜  api git:(master) ✗ kubectl get services
NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
ignoble-hyena-redis-master     ClusterIP   10.100.187.188   <none>        6379/TCP         5h21m
ignoble-hyena-redis-slave      ClusterIP   10.100.236.164   <none>        6379/TCP         5h21m
```

```
MacBook-Pro ➜  api git:(master) ✗ kubectl describe service ignoble-hyena-redis-master
Name:              ignoble-hyena-redis-master
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=redis
                   chart=redis-9.0.1
                   heritage=Tiller
                   release=ignoble-hyena
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=redis,release=ignoble-hyena,role=master
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.100.187.188
Port:              redis  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        redis/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.34.46:6379
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Do I use: `redis://my-password@ignoble-hyena-redis-master:6379`. That seems fragile as the pod name changes every time I redeploy the Helm chart. What is the recommended way to handle internal service discovery within the Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 2):

You should [package your application as a Helm chart](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#charts).  This basically involves running `helm create`, then copying your existing deployment YAML into the `templates` directory.  [Charts can have dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#chart-dependencies) and so you can declare that your application needs Redis.  Using the version in the [standard Helm charts repository](https://github.com/helm/charts) you can say something like

```
# I am requirements.yaml
- name: redis
  version: ~9.0.2
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

The important detail here is that your application and its Redis will have the same Helm release name -- if your application is `ignoble-hyena-myapp` then its Redis will be `ignoble-hyena-redis-master`.  You can set this in your deployment YAML spec using templates

```
env:
  - name: REDIS_HOST
    value: {{ .Release.Name }}-redis-master
```

Because of the way Kubernetes works internally, even if you `helm upgrade` your chart to a newer image tag, it won't usually touch the Redis.  Helm will upload a new version of the Redis artifacts that looks exactly the same as the old one, and Kubernetes will take no action.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t find it well-documented but following the template code you should be able to set the [`fullnameOverride` value](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/0d79ef1562572e554d08046b02bae07f4f9524cc/stable/redis/README.md#L134) to some string you control, and the redis master will be exposed as `<yourFullname>-master`, and you can have your clients reach it via that. If your clients are in a different namespace, they can reach the masters at `<yourFullname>-master.<redisMasterServiceNamespace>`.